# Passing a class variable in a def python

Tags: python, function, class

I have a python code where I am trying to ask the user for first/last name, email, and there pin code.

I got this to work without making a def, but I wanted to put the def in the class to make things look nicer.

My issue is that I have no idea how to use my class variable `Usr` to set the `Usr.pin` in the `def`

This is what I have...

```py
class Usr:
    def __init__(self, fName, lName, email, pin):
        self.fName = fName
        self.lName = lName
        self.email = email
        self.pin = pin`

    def pinChecker(self, usrData, checker): #the int checker is passed into the code as 1
        while (checker < 2):

            for x in range(len(usrData)):
                if self.pin in usrData[x].pin or (len(self.pin) != 4) or (not self.pin.isdigit()):
                    print('Pin is invalid, please try again')
                    self.pin = input('Please enter in pin again: ')
                else:
                    checker = checker + 1

        return self.pin
```

and the function to call it saves the return

```
pin = Usr.pinChecker(Usr.pin, usrData, checker) #usrData is an empty list
```

Overall I am confused about how to pass the `Usr.pin` correctly.

Comment: You aren't creating an *instance* of your class. `u = Usr(....)`, then `pin = u.pinChecker(...)`.

Comment: There is no ``Usr.pin`` anywhere in your definition of ``Usr``!

Comment: Can you clarify how you expect your class to be used, or what your goal even is? What is your question?

Comment: The answer below has solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create an instance of your class, then you can call its methods:

```py
user = Usr('Marsellus', 'Wallace', 'marsellus.wallace@gmail.com', '1234')
user.pinChecker()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're approaching this the wrong way. You have a `Usr` class which presumably represents some sort of user's state, but use `Usr.pin` to represent some user input, not the actual PIN? Let's invert that logic.

```py
class User(object):  # we're not gaining anything by dropping the 'e' -- be explicit

    PIN_RETRIES = 2

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email, pin):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.email = email
        self.pin = pin

    def check_pin(self):
        for i in range(self.PIN_RETRIES):  # try up to PIN_RETRIES times
            attempt = input("Enter your PIN: ")
            if attempt == self.pin:
                print "Success"
                return True
            else:
                retry_attempts = self.PIN_RETRIES - i - 1
                print(f"Wrong PIN, {retry_attempts:d} {'try' if retry_attempts == 1 else 'tries'} left")
        else:
            # if we fail PIN_RETRIES times:
            return False
```

Then we can check it out in a REPL:

```
>>> user = User('Adam', 'Smith', 'myemail@mydomain.com', '1234')
>>> user.check_pin()
Enter your PIN: 1233
Wrong PIN, 1 try left
Enter your PIN: 1234
Success
```